# Is there a way to 'create' the input arguments of a process iteratively (iterator) as other processes finish with multiprocessing.Pool() of Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have to do an operation in which a function receives a big [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe, performs some calculations and returns a result (each iteration takes ~1 min). I have to repeat this operation several times by "passing" this pandas dataframe to the function (~5000 times).

I have decided to use the Python library [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to perform all these operations, as they are independent between them. However, when using the [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) method (with imap), all the values that are passed as input of the function that is going to be parallelized are inferred at once (first get a list with all the inputs and the parallelize). In my case, this results in a very big list of pandas dataframes that gives memory issues (it is a list with the same pandas dataframe repeated several times).

Is there a way to create an iterator and generate new inputs (the pandas dataframe) as the processes that are currently running finish?

Next it is shown a small dummy example in which all the inputs are calculated at once and then the function `do_something()` is parallelized (this is not the behaviour that I want):

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def do_something(a):
    print(f"Sleep {a}")
    time.sleep(1)
    return a**2, a + a


def test_multiprocessing(inputs):
    class data_generator:
        def __init__(self, inputs):
            self.inputs = inputs
            self.i = 0

        def __next__(self):
            if self.i >= len(self):
                raise StopIteration
            return_value = self.inputs[self.i]
            self.i += 1
            print(f"Input id: {self.i}")
            return return_value

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.inputs)

    # Parallelize
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as executor:
        results = executor.imap(do_something, data_generator(inputs))
        executor.close()
        executor.join()

    for result in results:
        print(result)
    print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputs = [(i) for i in range(1, 30)]
    test_multiprocessing(inputs)
```

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Your iterator would need to handle the process of requesting a new input. How are you creating your inputs initially? Is there some reason this input generation can't be integrated into `data_generator.__next__()`?

Comment: Well, this is a dummy example, but the actual generator should receive a dataframe as input, do some operations inside and the output will be a chunk of this dataframe (each time a different chunk, but different generated datasets intersect between them).